# loop not completing its iteration in C

Tags: c, loops

I am however having trouble with my game loop! Currently when an invalid move is made, the loop iterates correctly. However when a valid move is made, my program displays the changed board, however appears to freeze in the middle of the loop! i have the location where it freezes (Test Spot 2 in the code), but i have no clue why. The desired output of my code is to keep on iterating until there are no moves available. (I haven't created the check for no moves yet as I cannot get my code to run in a normal counted loop!)

The code working when it is Invalid and not when it is valid is shown below.
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RahMr.png)

Main Function where the issue occurs

```
int main(void)
{
    int n;
    int p;
    char oppChar;
    char playChar;
    int i;
    int pTurn;
    int deltaRow;
    int deltaCol;
    int endGame = 999;

    printf("Enter the board dimension: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Computer plays (B/W) ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf(" %c", &oppChar);

    if (oppChar == 'B') {
        pTurn = 0;
        playChar = 'W';
    } else {
        pTurn = 1;
        playChar = 'B';
    }

    char board[n][26];
    int movesAvalB[n][26];
    int movesAvalW[n][26];
    int AIBoard[n][26];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (p = 0; p < n; p++) {
            board[i][p] = 'U';
        }
    }

    board[(n / 2) - 1][(n / 2) - 1] = 'W';
    board[(n / 2) - 1][(n / 2)] = 'B';
    board[(n / 2)][(n / 2) - 1] = 'B';
    board[n / 2][n / 2] = 'W';
    printBoard(board, n);


    int q = 0;
    do {
        q++;
        // testing
        printf(" \n");
        printf("Turn Number %d \n", pTurn);


        // variable decleration
        int k = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int max = 0;
        int temp = 0;
        char c[3] = " ";

        // arrays are all 0
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (p = 0; p < n; p++) {
                AIBoard[i][p] = 0;
                movesAvalB[i][p] = 0;
                movesAvalW[i][p] = 0;
            }
        }

        // moves avaliable to W
        for (y = 0; y < n; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x < n; x++) {
                if (moves(n, x, y, board, 'W')) {
                    movesAvalW[y][x] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("Test Spot 1\n");

        // moves avaliable to B
        for (y = 0; y < n; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x < n; x++) {
                if (moves(n, x, y, board, 'B')) {
                    printf("Test Spot 1.5\n");
                    movesAvalB[y][x] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("Test Spot 2\n");

        // pTurn = pTurn%2;
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("Enter a move for colour %c (RowCol): \n", playChar);
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%s", &c);

        if (positionInBounds(n, c[0], c[1])) {
            int y = c[0] - 97;
            int x = c[1] - 97;

            if (playChar == 'B') {
                if (movesAvalB[y][x] == 1) {
                    for (deltaRow = -1; deltaRow <= 1; deltaRow++) {
                        for (deltaCol = -1; deltaCol <= 1; deltaCol++) {
                            if (positionIntBounds(n, (x + deltaRow), (y + deltaCol))) {
                                i = 1;

                                while ((positionIntBounds(n, (y + (i * deltaRow)), (x + (i * deltaCol)))) &&
                                       (board[y + (i * deltaRow)][x + (i * deltaCol)] == 'W')) {

                                    i++;
                                    if ((positionIntBounds(n, (y + (i * deltaRow)), (x + (i * deltaCol)))) &&
                                        (board[y + (i * deltaRow)][x + (i * deltaCol)] == 'B')) {
                                        while (i != 0) {
                                            i--;
                                            board[y + (i * deltaRow)][x + (i * deltaCol)] = 'B';
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    for (deltaRow = -1; deltaRow <= 1; deltaRow++) {
                        for (deltaCol = -1; deltaCol <= 1; deltaCol++) {
                            if (board[y + deltaRow][x + deltaCol] == 'W') {
                                board[y + deltaRow][x + deltaCol] == 'B';
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    printBoard(board, n);

                } else {
                    printf("Invalid Move.");
                }
            }

            if (playChar == 'W') {
                if (movesAvalW[y][x] == 1) {
                    for (deltaRow = -1; deltaRow <= 1; deltaRow++) {
                        for (deltaCol = -1; deltaCol <= 1; deltaCol++) {
                            if (positionIntBounds(n, (x + deltaRow), (y + deltaCol))) {
                                i = 1;

                                while ((positionIntBounds(n, (y + (i * deltaRow)), (x + (i * deltaCol)))) &&
                                       (board[y + (i * deltaRow)][x + (i * deltaCol)] == 'B')) {

                                    i++;
                                    if ((positionIntBounds(n, (y + (i * deltaRow)), (x + (i * deltaCol)))) &&
                                        (board[y + (i * deltaRow)][x + (i * deltaCol)] == 'W')) {
                                        while (i != 0) {
                                            i--;
                                            board[y + (i * deltaRow)][x + (i * deltaCol)] = 'W';
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    for (deltaRow = -1; deltaRow <= 1; deltaRow++) {
                        for (deltaCol = -1; deltaCol <= 1; deltaCol++) {
                            if (board[y + deltaRow][x + deltaCol] == 'B') {
                                board[y + deltaRow][x + deltaCol] == 'W';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    printBoard(board, n);

                } else {
                    printf("Invalid Move.");
                }
            }
        } else {
            printf("Invalid Move.");
        }
        pTurn++;

    } while (q <= 5);
    printf("were out");
}
```

Secondary Functions which you probably don't need but maybe

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void printBoard(char board[][26], int n)
{
    int i;
    char alpha[27] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    printf(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%c", alpha[i]);
    }

    int p;
    int q;
    for (p = 0; p < n; p++) {
        printf("\n");
        printf("%c", alpha[p]);
        for (q = 0; q < n; q++) {
            printf("%c", board[p][q]);
        }
    }
}

bool positionInBounds(int n, char row, char col)
{
    int p = row - 97;
    int d = col - 97;

    if (p > n) {
        return false;
    }
    if (d > n) {
        return false;
    }
    if (0 > p) {
        return false;
    }
    if (0 > d) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool positionIntBounds(int n, int row, int col)
{
    if (row > n) {
        return false;
    }
    if (col > n) {
        return false;
    }
    if (0 > row) {
        return false;
    }
    if (0 > col) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool checkLegalInDirection(char board[][26], int n, char row, char col, char colour, int deltaRow, int deltaCol)
{
    int i = 0;

    while ((positionIntBounds(n, (row + (i * deltaRow)), (col + (i * deltaCol)))) &&
           (board[row + (i * deltaRow)][col + (i * deltaCol)] != colour) &&
           (board[row + (i * deltaRow)][col + (i * deltaCol)] != 'U')) {
        i++;
        if ((positionIntBounds(n, (row + (i * deltaRow)), (col + (i * deltaCol)))) &&
            (board[row + (i * deltaRow)][col + (i * deltaCol)] == colour)) {

            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool moves(int n, int x, int y, char board[][26], char colour)
{

    int deltaRow;
    int deltaCol;

    if (board[y][x] == 'U') {

        for (deltaRow = -1; deltaRow <= 1; deltaRow++) {
            for (deltaCol = -1; deltaCol <= 1; deltaCol++) {
                if (positionIntBounds(n, (x + deltaRow), (y + deltaCol))) {

                    if (checkLegalInDirection(board, n, (x + deltaRow), (y + deltaCol), colour, deltaRow, deltaCol)) {

                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

(I was told to put fflush(stdout) before my scanf statements but this didnt fix the problem)

Comment: You will probably solve this problem faster by using a debugger instead of waiting for someone to wade through your code.

Comment: can you suggest a debugger? Ive never used one

Comment: Which platform are you on?  Which compiler are you using?  GDB and LLDB are good for GCC and Clang respectively.

Comment: The debugger shows it stopping in the middle of this loop when x = 0 and y = 2. I HAVE NO CLUE WHY HOWEVER.                                        // moves avaliable to B
        for (y = 0; y < n; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x < n; x++) {
                if (moves(n, x, y, board, 'B')) {
                    printf("Test Spot 1.5\n");
                    movesAvalB[y][x] = 1;
                }
            }
        }

Comment: You can't do programming without a debugger...

Comment: The posted code causes the compiler to output MANY warnings.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`,at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 )

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", &c);`  1) when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) in C, referencing the name of an array degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.  3) when using the format specifier '%s' and/or '%[...]' always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer.  Because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input. (cont)

Comment: (cont)  This results in the buffer never being overflowed.  Such overflow is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest: 1if( scanf( "%2s", c ) != 1 ) { // handle input failure  and exit }`

Comment: regarding, in function: `main()`,  `if (board[y + deltaRow][x + deltaCol] == 'B') {
                                board[y + deltaRow][x + deltaCol] == 'W'; }`   AND `if (board[y + deltaRow][x + deltaCol] == 'W') {
                                board[y + deltaRow][x + deltaCol] == 'B';
                            }`   The statement in the body of the `if()` statements has no effect.  Your compiler should have told you this

Comment: regarding this statement: `if (checkLegalInDirection(
                        board,
                        n,
                        (x + deltaRow),
                        (y + deltaCol),
                        colour,
                        deltaRow,
                        deltaCol))`   the third and forth parameters are declared to be 'char', but are being passed an 'int'  in C, promotion of a parameter is ok, but not demotion.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) honor the right margin of a page (typically column 72 or 80) by breaking the statement at a reasonable point and continuing the statement (indented) on the next line.

Comment: regarding the functions: `positionInBounds()` and `positionIntBounds()`  it is poor programming practice to have multiple functions those only difference in the name is capitalization, a digit, or a single character.